# set tx power level in CSR8510 using hcitool

Tags: bluetooth

I have a generic USB Bluetooth LE dongle, which uses the CSR-8510 chip.  I've found some documentation that suggests that this chip has multiple TX power levels.

Is there a way (perhaps with "hcitool cmd...") to reduce the TX power?  (By default, it's about 7dBm, but I'd like to make it lower, eg -20 dBm or so.  This is for LE mode, for use as an iBeacon clone.)